# Adding next and previous button to a Jquery Carousel's Thumbnail images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm interested in adding a next and previous button to an existing jquery carousel. Clicking the next button would select the thumbnail on the right of the previously selected thumbnail, which will also consequently change the larger picture. Clicking the previous button would result in selection of the thumbnail to the left. Looping is optional, but would be preferred (clicking the right button when the last image is selected should select the first image and vice versa).

I've attached a link to the script below:
http://jsfiddle.net/SRNBn/

Here's the code starting with the html:

```
<div id="imgDetail">
<img src="http://www.davidwightman.net/_images_landscape/Behemot/Behemot_detail_1.jpg" alt="" id="bigImg" />
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://www.davidwightman.net/_images_landscape/Behemot/Behemot_detail_1.jpg" class="thumb" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.davidwightman.net/_images_landscape/Behemot/Behemot_detail_2.jpg"  class="thumb" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.davidwightman.net/_images_landscape/Behemot/Behemot_detail_3.jpg" class="thumb" /></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.thumb { width: 75px; height: 75px; } li { display: inline; margin-right: 10px; }
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#imgDetail li img').hover(function(){
    $('#bigImg').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$('#next').on('click',function(){
 var imgSrc = $('#bigImg').attr('src');
    var nextSrc = $('ul img[src="'+imgSrc+'"]').closest('li').next().find('img').attr('src');
    console.log(nextSrc);
    nextSrc ==undefined?$('#bigImg').attr('src',$('ul img:first').attr('src')): $('#bigImg').attr('src',nextSrc);
});
$('#prev').on('click',function(){
 var imgSrc = $('#bigImg').attr('src');
    var nextSrc = $('ul img[src="'+imgSrc+'"]').closest('li').prev().find('img').attr('src');
    console.log(nextSrc);
    nextSrc ==undefined?$('#bigImg').attr('src',$('ul img:last').attr('src')): $('#bigImg').attr('src',nextSrc);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/SRNBn/214/)

Comment: That's fantastic- Thanks, Anton. I realize I have one follow up question- is it possible to display only 5 thumbnails, and have the next/previous buttons reveal more thumbnails. So lets say that I have 9 pictures total; when the page load only the first 5 will be available, with the first being selected. The first 4 times the next button is clicked, different pictures would be selected. On the 5th time next is clicked, the thumbnail images would slide to accomodate the 6th image (showing pictures 2 - 6), and so on for the next images.

Comment: here are additional images that you can use to save you some time: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/Winnersh_Meadows_Trees.jpg
http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02296/animal4c_2296997i.jpg
http://megahdwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Animal-Sea-Animals-257824.jpg
http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSgP0k5JWnD_6UKq6GNmLVnGuBgcrzAb-ApxLa2SnlWZqmu22qDKA 
http://photographyblog.dallasnews.com/files/2012/10/animal-1.jpg